# Handling json response in .ejs page node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I am very much beginner with node.js!

I am unable to handle json response in .ejs page.
Its when user tries logging in with wrong details then I am rendering same page and sending some JSON response and checking if this sent response is not null then show some alert or something like "Unidentified details".

```
 res.redirect('login', { LoginInvalid: "LoginInvalid" });
```

**Using response in page-**

```
<script>
    if(JSON.stringify(<%-LoginInvalid%>)!=null){
    console.log('invalid details'); 
    }
</script>
```

But this script doesn't run and page shows me reference error with  `LoginInvalid is not defined`

Please guid me troubleshooting this tiny issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a variable to your ejs template if you are using `res.redirect()` (Read http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect for more information). If you do want to pass some variable in it, the only way is to use GET query string like this

```
res.redirect('login?LoginInvalid=LoginInvalid');
```

And parse LoginInvalid query string from the login controller.

Answer (score -1):

You can use flash messages with the [express-flash](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-flash) module.

```
var flash = require('express-flash');

app.use(flash());
```

Then in your route,

```
req.flash('login', { LoginInvalid: "LoginInvalid" });
res.redirect('/login');
```

And in your view,

```
<% if (messages.login.LoginInvalid) { %>
    <%= messages.login.LoginInvalid
<% } %>
```